# conflicting jQuery scripts, two different toggle functions affecting eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, conflict

i have these two scripts:

```
    // Show the stats slide out
$(document).on('click','.buildscore',function(){     
    $(".buildscore2").slideToggle();
});

// Hide / show the comments
$(document).on('click','#hideshow',function(){       
    $('.commentsbox').toggle();
    $('.commentsboxhidden').toggle();
});
```

The comments toggle works fine, and so does the buildscore. But the buildscore stats slide out function also toggles the comments box divs.

Check out the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FsUDj/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Elements need to have unique IDs. You gave both buttons the same "hideshow" ID. You need target the elements based on what you want to happen, and give them the appropriate attributes.

Comment: typical. Im pondering over things for hours... put it on here and its something silly like that. I was thinking way more complex... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Simple HTML, with unique ids and only the necessary tags:

```
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='Comments On / Off'>
<div class="commentsbox">COMMENT</div>
<input type='button' id="buildscore" value='STATS'>
<div class="buildscore">STATS</div>
```

Simple JQuery, with no unnecessary bits:

```
// Show the stats slide out
$('#buildscore').click(function(){     
    $(".buildscore").slideToggle();
});
// Hide / show the comments
$('#hideshow').click(function(){      
    $('.commentsbox').toggle();
});
```

Comment: the .on method had to be used because i was using .load() on my content. After the .load(), no buttons would work unless i was using .on. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: If you don't use anonymous inner functions, but rather assign them to a var, then attach them via click once the code is loaded, that would also work. Meaning, have `var toggle = function(elm) { $(elm).toggle(); }` and in the .load() do `$('#id').click(toggle);`.